# In the movie 北京遇上西雅图 (Finding Mr. Right), what does 文佳佳 mean when she yells “像话么，你”?

Tags: meaning, spoken

In the movie [北京遇上西雅图](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finding_Mr._Right) (~6m), the protagonist 文佳佳 yells at the driver for being late.  She rants:

> [image: photo of my TV]
>
> 我是花钱买服务的，我整整坐了12个小时的飞机，我需要休息。你知道吗？小心点，这箱子很贵啊！你赔不起，我告诉你。我告诉你 我要投诉你们，你看别人都拿着个牌子举着等人。早早地就来了，你倒好，恨不得。干脆这样吧。你给我地址，我拿着牌子去接你好了，**像话么，你**！你知道天儿有多冷吗？

She says it twice (~7m), actually, after she realizes the driver has pet mice in the back seat:

> [image: photo of my TV]
>
> 无菌什么呀，你把老鼠和孕妇关一块你**像话么，你**。你这车我坐不了。

I'm not clear on this, but since [像话](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%83%8F%E8%AF%9D) means ["proper"](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%83%8F%E8%AF%9D), this appears to be a kind of complaint phrased as a rhetorical question (something like 你太过分了), or perhaps it's a spoken Chinese or dialect matter.

**Question**: What does 文佳佳 mean when she yells “像话么，你”?

Comment: 不像话 means nonsensical or outrageous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

像话么，你? It is a rhetorical question, and it is not a dialect. Pretty much everyone use this.

You thoughts about 像话么，你 is correct. Let's look back to sentences before that

> 我是花钱买服务的，我整整坐了12个小时的飞机，我需要休息。你知道吗？小心点，这箱子很贵啊！你赔不起，我告诉你。我告诉你 我要投诉你们，你看别人都拿着个牌子举着等人。早早地就来了，你倒好，恨不得。干脆这样吧。你给我地址，我拿着牌子去接你好了，

All above is bunch of complain and sarcasm， and so she asked “don't you think this is improper?”
obviously she isn't expecting the the driver to answer the question.

For the second one:

> 无菌什么呀，你把老鼠和孕妇关一块。

Basically she complain about how can driver put a mice (driver seems to claim back seat is a clean environment) with pregnant woman.
So she there goes her second rhetorical question.

How do i know driver's claim:
'无菌什么呀' is a expression similar to when someone tells you my bedroom is so clean when you see tons of trash. Then you might reply "clean my ***"

To simply answer to your question:
She means "Don't you think this isn't proper?" or "How can you treat me / behave like this"

Answer (score 1):

As you quoted, 像话 means *proper* or *something right*.  不像话 means *improper* or *something wrong/crazy*.

E. g.  你有点不像话了。 // You behaved a bit improperly. (probably a bit crazy).